# QGIS - Find the shortest path on ORS Tools

Tags: qgis, distance, shortest-path

I have got two layers:

- Point Layer 1 that has got random 'houses' in a town
- Point Layer 2 that has got all the post offices in the town

My aim is to find the shortest path from each house from layer 1 to their closest post office in layer 2. I have tried to use QNEAT3 but it would only calculate the distance from each single house to all the post offices in town. I therefore decided to move to ORS Tools but I don't seem to make it work with the conditions that I require to calculate.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and managed to solve it?